# Average calls per week for each Month

Tags: sql-server, average

Hi I would like to get average calls per week for each month
Also, average calls per week for each Quarter
Also, average calls per week for each Year

I need a query for each of the above.  Thank you for your help!

Below is the raw data set:

```
Name    Call        CallDate
Jack    Phone Call  2017-03-10
Laura   Meeting     2017-03-08
Helen   Phone Call  2017-02-02
Sam     Video Conf  2017-02-10
David   Skype       2017-01-01
Jack    Skype       2017-01-14
Laura   Video Conf  2014-03-09
Helen   Meeting     2017-02-12
Sam     Meeting     2017-02-12
David   Meeting     2017-03-09
David   Video Conf  2017-02-25
David   Skype       2017-02-20
Jack    Skype       2017-02-20
Jack    Phone Call  2017-03-10
Laura   Phone Call  2017-02-07
Laura   Skype       2017-02-07
Sam     Phone Call  2017-03-04
Sam     Phone Call  2017-03-04
Sam     Skype       2017-03-10
```

Comment: your question makes no sense. A week can be part of 2 months, Even 2 years. Making an average like that needs very clear specifications

Answer (score 1):

Best effort since your question is strange.

This will count the calls in each month divide it with the days in the month and multiply by 7

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, cast(CallDate as datetime)), 0) month
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT
  -- day(eomonth(month)) calculates the number of days in the month
  count(*)*7./day(eomonth(month)) avgweeklycallsmonth,
  month
FROM CTE
GROUP BY month
```

This will count the calls in each quarter divide it with the days in the quarter and multiply by 7

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter,0, CallDate), 0) quarter
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT 
  count(*)*7./
    (datediff(day,dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, quarter), 0),
      dateadd(month,3, quarter))) avgweeklycallsquarter, 
  quarter
FROM CTE
GROUP BY quarter
```

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk.  Thank you for the answer.  I also want to group by Name, month, and averageweeklycallsmonth, how do I do that?  So the result should show the averageweeklycallsmonth for the person's name.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, could you setup the query so that I can add the query into a view and to be able to select any column from the table?  Thank you

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk.  When you say divide by the days in the month, how is that done?  There are different number of days in a month

Comment: @peppe you are adding new questions to this question. If you need new answers. You need to ask a new question. The calculation for number of days in the month has been added as a comment in the code

Comment: This looks like a pretty good guess at making some precise rules around a vague requirement. Well done.